# Connection error to mssql from Centos7

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, centos7, sqlcmd

I have Centos7 installation with nginx/php5.6. MS SQL 2008 R2 is working on another server.
MSSQL definitely has allowed tcp connection, custom (non domain) user, firewall disabled, and I can connect to it using HeidiSQL and that setting from another Windows machine. 
I can telnet to MSSQL from Centos (and I see Log error "Length specified in network packet payload did not match number of bytes read; the connection has been closed. Please contact the vendor of the client library." with centos ip address in MSSQL logs, so no errors here).

I couldn't connect to mssql from centos using php_mssql or sqlcmd;

During sqlcmd:

```
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Command Line Tool
Version 13.1.0007.0 Linux

[root@***]# /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S *** -U ***
Password:
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Timeout error [258]. .
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : Unable to complete login process due to delay in prelogin response.
```

During php interactive:

```
php > mssql_connect('***:***', '***','***');
PHP Warning:  mssql_connect(): Unable to connect to server: *** in php shell code on line 1
```

I also tried tsql/freetds:

```
/etc/freetds.conf has section
[myserver]
        host = ***
        port = ***
        client charset = UTF-8
        tds version = 8.0 //also tried 7

[root@*]# tsql -S myserver -U ***
Password:
locale is "en_US.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
 5 //begins to count, i could't understand what does it mean
```

Also tried to clean it all and install php7.0 with sqlsrv extension - the same problem;

There are some network strange - Centos serv and MSSQL are in different networks, I couldnt ping mssql from that server, but can telnet, i'm using ip, not the host name during connection attempts, so don't think it's a big deal.

Now I am out of ideas where to dig, any suggestions, please?

Comment: Have you tried to use [PDO with dblib driver](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php)? Work great on debian with php 5.6 and MSSQL Server 2k8...

Comment: @Ayak973 Thank you for your idea, yep, the same error. But the problem was solved, it was caused by misconfiguration in network, i don't understand exactly how it is possible - to make telnet connection, but fail to connect normally, but our IT guys repaired this problem in less then half an hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was caused by misconfiguration in the network, I don't understand exactly how it is possible - to make telnet connection, but fail to connect normally, but our IT guys repaired this problem in less then half an hour.